# What is wrong with my switch statement?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, switch-statement

I have this block of code that is giving me some trouble:

```
switch(errorNum){
case 404:

    //Send back a 404 error
    char outputBuf[MAXREQUESTLENGTH];
    int outputLength = sprintf(outputBuf, "%s/r/n/r/n%s/r/n", "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found","<html><body><h1>404 Page Not Found</h1></body></html>");
    char output[outputLength + 1];
    if(strcpy(output, outputBuf) == NULL){
    die("strcpy error");
    }
    if(send(socketFD, output, outputLength, 0) != outputLength){
    die("send error");
    }       
    break;
```

When I compile my program with this bit of code in it, I am getting these errors,

```
http-server.c: In function 'returnError':
http-server.c:28:6: error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement
http-server.c:29:6: error: expected expression before 'int'
http-server.c:30:18: error: 'outputLength' undeclared (first use in this function)
http-server.c:30:18: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Could somebody please explain what these errors mean? From what I can tell I did declare outputLength in this line:

```
 int outputLength = sprintf(outputBuf, "%s/r/n/r/n%s/r/n", "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found","<html><body><h1>404 Page Not Found</h1></body></html>");
```

and I am not sure what could be expected to go before `int`. As for the label error I'm not sure why I am getting that because I don't believe I am using labels. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read the error for 28:6 as it literally tells you what's wrong. Move the declarations outside of the switch and see if the error disappears.

Comment: if the error disappears, as @lurker suggests, then you have an older compiler,  place a '{' after the case 404: statement and a '}' before the break; statement.  However I would suspect the problem is actually before the switch() statement.  is the variable errorNum defined? is the constant MAXREQUESTLENGTH defined?  does the statement before the switch() statement end with a ';'?

Comment: I would suggest adding a 'default: // handle error break; as the last case as some older compilers would not properly terminate a switch() scope, such that if no case was matched, the program would crash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot have declarations right in the middle in between case labels. However, you can simply introduce a new local scope inside which you can have declarations:

```
switch (errorNum)
{
    case 404:
    {
        //Send back a 404 error
        char outputBuf[MAXREQUESTLENGTH];
        int outputLength = /* ... */
        break;
    }
    case 405:
        foo();
        break;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really see the difference between this and what I am doing. I believe I am also making variables within the case that have local scope, I am not trying to use them outside of the case.

Comment: @guribe94: the braces!